# Python Flask validate_on_submit() https error

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, http-status-code-405

Help I am stuck here for almost 3 days and now I am posting my doubt hear
my code shows 405 error

```
@app.route("/category/add")
def add_category():
    form = AddCategory()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_category = Categories(
            title=form.name.data,
            description=form.description.data,
            review=form.review.data,
            img_url=form.img_url.data,
        )
        db.session.add(new_category)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("index.html")
    return render_template("add_category.html", form=form)
```

```
class AddCategory(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField(label='Category name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = StringField(label='Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    review = StringField(label='Review', validators=[DataRequired()])
    img_url = StringField(label='Image Url ', validators=[DataRequired(), URL()])
    submit = SubmitField(label='Add')
```

it runs perfect till the condition statement

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf%}

{% block styles %}
  {{ super() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:300,400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Add Category{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content">
    <h1 class="heading">Add a Category</h1>
    {{wtf.quick_form(form, novalidate=True)}}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

add_category.html

Comment: Are there any errors on the console? 

It is likely that the form data is sent as a POST request - @app.route("/category/add",methods = ['GET','POST']) allows for that, 405 indicated method not allowed and the default isvGET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Mandraenke's comment is right. Now, your route allows only GET method, by form.validate_on_submit() presumes POST method. So you need to specify it explicitly. Like that:

```
@app.route("/category/add", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_category():
    form = AddCategory()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_category = Categories(
            title=form.name.data,
            description=form.description.data,
            review=form.review.data,
            img_url=form.img_url.data,
        )
        db.session.add(new_category)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("index.html")
    return render_template("add_category.html", form=form)
```